# Where is Windows Authentication library located?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-sct

I want to use AWS Schema Conversion Tool to migrate from SQL Server to Redshift.

When using the tool a path to Windows Authentication library should be specified.

Where is it located?

[image]

Comment: Isn't this is explained at [Using Microsoft SQL Server as a source for AWS SCT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html)?

Comment: I can't find anything about where Windows Authentication library is located in that documentation

Comment: Check the "Using Windows Authentication with a JDBC connection" section of that page about how to locate and copy the required `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file. Note also that this only works on Windows - if you're on another operating system you'll have to fallback to SQL Login authentication.

Comment: Your answer is valid but pointing to that dll results in "This driver is not configured for integrated authentication"

Comment: I see this mentioned in the documentation so it should be resolvable